# How to use poetry for recursive installation?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-poetry, pep517

I'm trying to install [this](https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode) repository using poetry package manager.
Here's how it's done using pip:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode.git
cd ctcdecode && pip install .
```

But if I try to run

```
poetry add ctcdecode
```

It fails with big traceback (over 200 lines I think).
So I installed it with

```
poetry run git clone --recursive https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode.git
poetry run pip install ./ctcdecode
```

But this way is not suitable for sharing with other devs.
Can I do it with pyproject.toml somehow?

Comment: The packaging of this project seems incorrect. I do not think it can be properly installed (well built actually) with poetry (or any other build frontend actually). You could file a bug and tell them to fix their packaging. In particular they should properly declare `torch` as a "build dependency".

Comment: @sinoroc thanks  for your answer. I'll point it out in repository. 
Sad to see popular repository not being packaged properly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`poetry add <packagename>` adds and installs a dependency available on pypi (or if configured other package repositories) to you project.

If you want to add a package, where the source code is located in a git repository use `poetry add git+<url_of_git>`.

The problem with `ctcdecode` in both ways is, that it needs to be build. For this `torch` is needed. `ctcdecode` doesn't declare this build dependency in a `pyproject.toml` according to [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).

You can work around it, by clone the git repository and put a `pyproject.toml` with this content into the project's folder:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "torch"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Then go back to your current project and add the local path dependency like this:

```sh
$ poetry add <relative_path_to_ctcdecode>
```

Comment: Would it work if I fork this repository and add ```pyproject.toml``` in it and then use ```poetry add git+{my_url.git}```?
As I need to distribute this project over other PCs.

Comment: The fork idea is good, it should work. I would recommend adding a specific git tag or git commit id as well if it makes sense. And then you wold need to keep your fork up to date for the upcoming releases.