# Install pycocotools with poetry( not PEP 517/518 compliant)

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry, pycocotools, pep517

I am trying to install [Pycocotools(PythonAPI)](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi) package with Poetry, but it fails to do so. As read in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247417/how-to-use-poetry-for-recursive-installation), it seems that this package is not packaged properly, and therefore poetry is unable to install it.

I tried to follow the procedure on linked question, but build failed. My purpose is to get this to work along with torch etc.

One option I guess is to submit an issue to the relevant package, but I dont think any changes will be made to their repo, so I am left probably with fixing it myself. Thanks

`poetry --version`  `#1.2.0a1`

`poetry add pycocotools`

> ```
>  Command ['/home/david/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/torch-coco-detection-l0t67CWY-py3.6/bin/python',
> ```
>
> '/home/david/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip',
> 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix',
> '/home/david/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/torch-coco-detection-l0t67CWY-py3.6',
> '--no-deps',
> 'file:/home/david/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/09/27/0c/fc4978bf6a0608be936e16316e3c2ded466882d6fea591754d92e4f931/pycocotools-2.0.2.tar.gz']
> errored with the following return code 1, and output:
> Processing /home/david/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/09/27/0c/fc4978bf6a0608be936e16316e3c2ded466882d6fea591754d92e4f931/pycocotools-2.0.2.tar.gz
> Installing build dependencies: started
> Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
> Getting requirements to build wheel: started
> Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork of poetry that I maintain called [relaxed-poetry](https://github.com/bennylut/relaxed-poetry) that relaxes some of the  enforcements that is made by poetry. It can install packages like `pycocotools` without errors. Give it a try if you think it can help you - it can be installed side by side with poetry.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while using pyenv, I just **downgraded the python version** which wasn't compatible with the project I was working on.

```
pyenv install 3.X.X 
pyenv global 3.X.X
poetry install
```